# facebook login not working in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I implemented facebook login in my website using 'react-facebook-login' [module](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login)

and I used this code in CompentDidMount

```
 `// Facebook Authentication
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '***********',
                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
                xfbml      : false,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
            });
        }.bind(this);
        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));`
```

In render function my code is

```
`                  <FacebookLogin
          appId="344596562557645"
          autoLoad={true}
          fields="name,email,picture.height(2048)"
          scope="public_profile, email"
          callback={this.responseFacebook.bind(this)}
          cssClass="fbbutton"
          icon="fa-facebook"
          textButton=" FACEBOOK"
          redirectUri={window.location.href}
/>`
```

Now login with facebook is perfectly working in desktop but not working in mobile browsers (both android and ios).In mobile browsers the callback function is not called because the the page is reloaded while in mobile. Please help me fix it , how to get data from that callback function.

Comment: Were you able to sort this issues? Can you share your solution if you did so ?

Comment: @Illep  fixed this by using this module - react-facebook-login-component

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fixed this issue. Added isMobile={false}

Answer (score 1):

are you using the redirect or the popup method? On mobile sometimes I've only had luck with the popup method. maybe that will help? not sure.

Comment: I am using pop up method working .But while in mobile it is redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using this module - [react-facebook-login-component](https://github.com/kennetpostigo/react-facebook-login-component)